# Panel will not collapse on Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Im new to bootstrap
Im trying this code and the collapse would not work
The button DROPXXX is not displayed
howcome?

In tutorials I saw, some of the address line will start with file:///.... and some with 127.0.0.0:9000/#
How (and what for) do I use the 127 local host adress? It doesnt display anything as I do it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar  navbar-inverse" >
      <a href="#" class = "navbar-brand">TECH</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">DROPXXX</button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="#">HOME</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works for me. The `DROPXXX` button appears on small resolutions, as expected. Maybe you misunderstood the `navbar-collapse` behaviour... [Check it out](http://www.bootply.com/NjH0w0SxaI)

Comment: still doesnt work for me. I checked the bootply you sent me. I cant see the DROPXXX at all. Wasnt I suppose to see it?
Could it be I miss some javascript whatever? I downloaded the jc files with the bootstrap

Comment: There was not a real problem, the OP misunderstood the expected behaviour.